# First view appears as black?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimage, splash-screen

I have a program where I'm working with user authentication and alert views. the problem is quite strange. Every *other* time I launch the application, the first view appears as normal, and then black, and then back to normal, and so on and so forth.

Launched once:

[image]

Launched twice:

[image]

Here's the storyboard:

[image]

Functionally, it's both the same, but I have no idea what could be causing this problem!

Addition:
The alert is called on viewdidappear.

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self presentAlertViewForPassword];
}
```

Addition 2 (build settings) (simulator is iphone 4):
[image]

Comment: What is your launch image?

Comment: the launch image is basically a uiimageview on the first page with an image in my directory

Comment: A launch image is something else. What is your default.png?

Comment: my launch image in my build settings is exactly what it looks like on the first screen (default.png)

Comment: Is this code at your rootviewcontroller or the tableviewcontroller?

Comment: this code is in rootviewcontroller (Christmas Root View Controller)

Comment: I am doing something absolutely different. Extending splashscreen. So after applicationDidFinish i add uiImageView with Default.png image. And i get same issue on ios7 every second build... Anyonw got solution? Seems only UIIMageView becomes black, the original view is displayed correct.

Answer (score 0):

Where do you have the AlertView show method? I think this could be because when you press the home button while you are at the UITableViewController and then you launch the app. This is where it starts from.
Do you have the login AlertView code in your applicationDidFinishLaunch?

Answer (score 0):

This black screen seems your alert's view screen. You can set its background image. Do one thing

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated 
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    UIImageView *iV = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds]; 
    iV.image = [UIImage imageWithNamed:@"imageNameHere"];
    [self.view addSubView:iV];

    [self presentAlertViewForPassword];
}
```

Set that Christmas Keeper image on view's background. Hope it helps. Also check your splash screen's image. Search `default.png` in search box of xcode may be this is different or may be there is two `default.png`. Just a guess :)

**Edit after notice your comment: the launch image is basically a uiimageview on the first page with an image in my directory**

So I think that black screen is your launch image because it appears before appearing the first view of your app. You didn't set it yet. Please include a `default.png` image into your project and it should be same as your first View's `imageView' image.

Comment: thanks for the feedback. it actually is already set this way! (added above)

Comment: Please set launch image for `retina-4` inch too.